# Request SQL : Join Table and don't want multiple value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck on an SQL query. The cause is since I added a table with a Left JOIN :

This my query, the issue is with `Amount_tax_excl`

```
SELECT [...]
  os.amount + os.shipping_cost_amount AS `amount`,
  (CASE 
    WHEN od.id_customization!=0 AND s.id_shop=3 THEN SUM(CAST(os.amount / 1.19 AS decimal(10,6)))
    WHEN od.id_customization!=0 AND s.id_shop=6 THEN SUM(osd.amount_tax_excl)
    WHEN od.id_customization!=0 AND s.id_shop!=3 THEN SUM(CAST(os.amount / 1.2 AS decimal(10,6)))
    ELSE SUM(osd.amount_tax_excl)
  END) AS amount_tax_excl,
  SUM(osd.amount_tax_incl) AS amount_tax_incl,
  os.shipping_cost_amount, os.partial,
  [...]
FROM  ps5_order_slip os
LEFT JOIN ps5_orders o ON (os.id_order = o.id_order)
LEFT JOIN ps5_order_detail od ON (o.id_order = od.id_order AND os.id_order = od.id_order)
LEFT JOIN ps5_shop s ON (o.id_shop = s.id_shop)
LEFT JOIN ps5_address a ON (o.id_address_delivery = a.id_address)
LEFT JOIN ps5_state e ON (a.id_state = e.id_state)
LEFT JOIN ps5_order_slip_detail osd ON (os.id_order_slip = osd.id_order_slip)
WHERE os.date_add >= '2019-07-01' AND os.date_add <= '2019-07-30 23:59:59'
GROUP BY os.id_order_slip
```

Normally, the result should be 645.35 like amount

https://i.stack.imgur.com/86TOT.jpg

I noticed that it's because of the order_detail table because there are 6 products.

So 645.35 * 6 = 3872.100000.
I use DISTINCT, IF ELSEIF, nothing works
I really need this variable od.id_customization for this query and it is that in this table.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeQIi.jpg

(Sorry I don't know how to display the images directly on the stack)

Thanks for help

Comment: `od.id_customization` is a property of individual line items, but you seem to be trying to use it as if it were a property of the whole order.  This is a semantic problem with your query.  Is it safe to rely on all the line items of the same order to have the same value for that property?  If not, then which one do you want to use when they don't all agree?

Comment: Also, is `id_order_slip` the primary key of table `ps5_order_slip`?  If indeed so, then you appear to have a lot more aggregation going on than you probably need.

Comment: @Winda welcome to Stack Overflow and good job in posting what you have so far. One piece of advice particularly when asking a question about a query is to not only provide your query that you have so far but also provide scripts that will create the tables and populate them with data. This way others are able to examine your problem a lot easier because they don't have to mock up the tables and the data themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining to order_detail table using only a header ID.  You need to join using line level ID.

Comment: Thaks for your answer but it's not order_slip_detail. The problem is ps5_order_detail.
Before adding it, it worked very well. Now I have to put it on to use id_customization

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. I have this mistake.

'osd.amount_tax_incl' unknown in field list

Comment: You mention the problem is with Amount_tax_excl which is why i assumed the new table that was added is ps5_order_slip_detail.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. a line level ID ?

Comment: You need to join to ps5_order_detail using a different key.  Post the schema for ps5_order_detail.

Comment: I feel like I can only use this ID 
https://imgur.com/4SYwH9G https://imgur.com/LquGqs6

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it but it's pretty dirty I think.

```
SELECT [...],
os.amount + os.shipping_cost_amount AS `amount`,
(CASE 
WHEN od.id_customization!=0 AND s.id_shop=3 THEN SUM(CAST(os.amount / 1.19 AS decimal(10,6))) / (Select COUNT(id_order) FROM ps5_order_detail WHERE id_order = os.id_order)
WHEN od.id_customization!=0 AND s.id_shop=6 THEN SUM(osd.amount_tax_excl) / (Select COUNT(id_order) FROM ps5_order_detail WHERE id_order = os.id_order)
WHEN od.id_customization!=0 AND s.id_shop!=3 THEN SUM(CAST(os.amount / 1.2 AS decimal(10,6))) / (Select COUNT(id_order) FROM ps5_order_detail WHERE id_order = os.id_order)
ELSE SUM(osd.amount_tax_excl) / (Select COUNT(id_order) FROM ps5_order_detail WHERE id_order = os.id_order)
END) AS amount_tax_excl,
SUM(osd.amount_tax_incl)  / (Select COUNT(id_order) FROM ps5_order_detail WHERE id_order = os.id_order) AS amount_tax_incl,
os.shipping_cost_amount, os.partial,
os.date_add, os.date_upd, e.`iso_code` AS `ISO Etat livraison`, e.`name` AS `Name Etat livraison`, a.city, o.`payment` AS `payment`
FROM  ps5_order_slip os
LEFT JOIN ps5_orders o ON (os.id_order = o.id_order)
LEFT JOIN  ps5_order_detail od ON (os.id_order = od.id_order)
[...]
```